# Filling NAs withing a variable depending on where they are located

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have data of the following sort:

```
> df <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(2000:2014), 2),
+                  Country=c(rep("Italy",15),rep("Germany",15)),
+                  var1= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20:21, NA, NA, NA, 27:28, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 74:77, NA, NA, 68:70, NA, NA))
> 
> df
   Date Country var1
1     1   Italy   NA
2     2   Italy   NA
3     3   Italy   NA
4     4   Italy   NA
5     5   Italy   NA
6     6   Italy   20
7     7   Italy   21
8     8   Italy   NA
9     9   Italy   NA
10   10   Italy   NA
11   11   Italy   27
12   12   Italy   28
13   13   Italy   NA
14   14   Italy   NA
15   15   Italy   NA
16    1 Germany   NA
17    2 Germany   NA
18    3 Germany   NA
19    4 Germany   NA
20    5 Germany   74
21    6 Germany   75
22    7 Germany   76
23    8 Germany   77
24    9 Germany   NA
25   10 Germany   NA
26   11 Germany   68
27   12 Germany   69
28   13 Germany   70
29   14 Germany   NA
30   15 Germany   NA
> 
> df1 <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(2000:2014), 2),
+                  Country=c(rep("Italy",15),rep("Germany",15)),
+                  var1= c(15.67052, 16.45405, 17.27675, 18.14059, 19.04762, 20:21, 22.36173, 23.81176, 25.35582, 27:28, 29.03704, 30.11249, 31.22777, 63.12417, 65.68326, 68.34609, 71.11688, 74:77, 73.87488, 70.8766, 68:70, 72.05882, 76.3599))
> 
> df1
   Date Country     var1
1     1   Italy 15.67052
2     2   Italy 16.45405
3     3   Italy 17.27675
4     4   Italy 18.14059
5     5   Italy 19.04762
6     6   Italy 20.00000
7     7   Italy 21.00000
8     8   Italy 22.36173
9     9   Italy 23.81176
10   10   Italy 25.35582
11   11   Italy 27.00000
12   12   Italy 28.00000
13   13   Italy 29.03704
14   14   Italy 30.11249
15   15   Italy 31.22777
16    1 Germany 63.12417
17    2 Germany 65.68326
18    3 Germany 68.34609
19    4 Germany 71.11688
20    5 Germany 74.00000
21    6 Germany 75.00000
22    7 Germany 76.00000
23    8 Germany 77.00000
24    9 Germany 73.87488
25   10 Germany 70.87660
26   11 Germany 68.00000
27   12 Germany 69.00000
28   13 Germany 70.00000
29   14 Germany 72.05882
30   15 Germany 76.35990
```

As you can see I have

1. "beginning NAs" i.e. NAs at the beginnning of the sampling period for each country;
2. "within NAs" i.e. NAs present in the middle of the sampling period as gaps in the data.
3. "ending NAs" i.e. NAs at the end of the sampling period when the data is not available yet, that is for the last couple of years.

I have a threefold goal:

1. make the "beginning NAs" grow at the same rate as the first two non-NAs are growing, or as another proxy country is growing.
2. Make the "within NAs" grow at a CAGR (Compound Annual Growth rate). I.e. each "within NA" growth factor is the ratio between the next available non-NA over the previous value elevated to the inverse of the number of years between the latter and the "within NA" in question. E.g. for Italy in year 9 the growth rate should be (27/(value in year 8))^(1/number of years between year 9 and 11)=(27/(value in year 8))^1/3
3. Make the "ending NAs" grow in different ways. Default should be simply grow as the last two non-NAs are growing. But when needed I need to make some country specific adjustments depending on assumptions (e.g. some countries where data is not available will be assumed to grow at the same rate as a proxy country is growing). Perhaps for this goal what's best is a loop that breaks for the exceptions.

The reason why it's so messy is that I have to automate an excel data processing that has been done in the past. Therefore, for as much as I'd like to change things (e.g. simply interpolate the within NA) I should follow what was done in the past.

Please use all your fantasy, however I'd love to remain within the DPLYR framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of what the final product should look like? Also can you post any code you've tried so far, even if it ends in an error message/bad result?

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid I don't follow the logic of "beginning NAs" and "within NAs" - can you give an example of the output from this dataset please?

Comment: thank you @jrcalabrese and Paul Stafford Allen . I have added your request